# How to calculate ratios for each category in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have data that looks like this

```
Category     Outcome
--------     -------
 A            Pass
 B            Pass
 A            Pass
 A            Fail
 B            Fail
 A            Unknown
 B            Unknown
 C            Pass
 C            Pass
```

I'd like to calculate the ratio for each category as `(Sum or all Passes)/((Sum of all Passes)+(Sum of all Fails))` and ignoring *Unknowns*.

The problem is that if I create a new `Measure` it will sum everything rather than individually for each category. I eventually want to plot these ratios in a bar chart for each category.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to make a bar chart showing the ratios for each category you can use the following meassure:

```
Ratio = CALCULATE(COUNT(Tabel1[Category]); Tabel1[Outcome]= "Pass" ) /
CALCULATE(COUNT(Tabel1[Category]); Tabel1[Outcome]= "Pass" || Tabel1[Outcome] = "Fail")
```

If you plot this ratio against Category you get your desired plot.